# php get cpanel username after login to protected directory

Tags: php, cpanel

We moved over to cpanel hosting last week.  I am creating password protected directories for users.  After the user has logged into the password protected directory I need to retrieve (via php) the username used to login to further display relevant info.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this url, hope it will help

http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess